# How do I make a SVG stretch to left and right, while maintaining aspect ratio in the middle?

Tags: svg

I have a three-part SVG. I would like to stretch the left and right parts infinitely, but keep the middle part intact.

Here’s the illustration.

[image]

I think my answer lies somewhere around `viewbox` tag `preserveAspectRatio` attribute of SVG. I haven't worked with them though, and could use a nudge in the right direction.

Here is the code for the unstretched SVG, which I think I need to somehow augment with viewboxes to achieve the desired stretching.

```
<svg width="48" height="17" viewBox="0 0 48 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<line y1="0.5" x2="32" y2="0.5" stroke="#FF0000"/>
<line x1="16" y1="8.5" x2="32" y2="8.5" stroke="#00FF00"/>
<line x1="16" y1="16.5" x2="48" y2="16.5" stroke="#0000FF"/>
</svg>
```

Here is the Codepen for code experiments: https://codepen.io/jaanus1/pen/aboQpeB

Answer (score 1):

Set: `width="100%" height="100%"`  `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 48 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<line y1="0.5" x2="32" y2="0.5" stroke="#FF0000"/>
<line x1="16" y1="8.5" x2="32" y2="8.5" stroke="#00FF00"/>
<line x1="16" y1="16.5" x2="48" y2="16.5" stroke="#0000FF"/>
</svg>
```

Update

I tried to make a new option.
Two lines red and green are included in one `SVG` block which is scaled.
The green line enters another SVG block, which has a fixed size: `width="48" height="17"`

To keep all lines the same width when zooming in, I added the property `vector-effect ="non-scaling-stroke"`

```css
.one {
  position:relative;
   }
  .two {
 position:absolute;
 top:35%;
 left:50%;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="one">
<svg width="100%" height="5%" viewBox="0 0 48 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<line vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" y1="0.5" x2="32" y2="0.5" stroke="#FF0000"/>

<line vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" x1="16" y1="16.5" x2="48" y2="16.5" stroke="#0000FF"/>
</svg>
<div class="two">
<svg width="48" height="17" viewBox="0 0 48 17">
<line x1="16" y1="8.5" x2="32" y2="8.5" stroke="#00FF00"/>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, because then the middle part also gets stretched, and I don't want that. Added this to my example Codepen and the image above.

Comment: @Jaanus In my opinion, this is a difficult task so that two `SVG` elements are scaled and the third element does not scale the green line 
I tried to make a new option

Comment: Of course it's difficult. That's why I'm posting here. If it was easy, I would have done it already :D

I'm interested in a pure-SVG solution, so I could easily use it as background image without any hacks (assuming all browsers support it). I can easily construct a thing of several images and divs, but that's not so interesting and would make my DOM more complex than it has to be.

Comment: There are some stretching examples here but I can't quite wrap my head around them. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Comment: @Jaanus I was also interested in your question, but so far, apart from using JS, there are no other thoughts. I’ll think more